# How to pass MAKE variables to guile

Tags: gnu-make, guile

I'm using GNU Make with Guile. How do I pass Make variables to Guile?

```
%.txt:
    @echo $* $(guile (string-upcase $*))
```

What I want to see is this:

```
$ make foo.txt
foo FOO
```

What I get is an error, `Unbound variable: foo`. My Guile invocation expands to `(string-upcase foo)`, and `foo` is unbound. I can put quotes around the variable and then I get the result I'm looking for:

```
$(guile (string-upcase "$*"))
```

This feels wrong. What if the string contains double quotes? It feels like there would be a more formal mechanism for passing values into Guile.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Guile-Types.html goes into some detail about passing values from Guile to to Make, but I can't immediately see anything about passing them *in*.

Comment: The example in the docs uses that `"$var"` style. You could probably use `subst` to escape double quotes if that's a concern.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn. Sometimes I forget that make programming is closer to shell programming than "real" programming in the sense that everything gets concatenated into a string and parsed out from a string; there are no higher-level constructs. The impedance mismatch with Guile is jarring :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gmk-expand` to expand `$*` more safely, like this:

```
%.txt:
        @echo $* $(guile (string-upcase (gmk-expand "$$*")))
```

Or you can use the following technique to bind unary functions so that they can be invoked with `$(call)`:

```
define _init :=
    (define (gmk-bind1 proc)
        (let ((name (symbol->string (procedure-name proc))))
             (gmk-eval (string-append
                        name "=$$(guile ("
                        name " (gmk-expand \"$$$$1\")))"))))
    (gmk-bind1 string-upcase)
endef
$(guile $(_init))

%.txt:
        echo $* $(call string-upcase,$*)
```